# Why are the checkboxes not being checked by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, prop

here is the html:

```
<input id="globalchecker" type="checkbox"/>

<input type="checkbox" class="childcheckboxes" />
<input type="checkbox" class="childcheckboxes" />
<input type="checkbox" class="childcheckboxes" />
<input type="checkbox" class="childcheckboxes" />
```

and here is the jquery:

```
$('#globalchecker').on('click', function () {
    if($('#globalchecker').is(":checked")){
        $('.childcheckboxes:checkbox').prop('checked',true);
    }
    else{
        $('.childcheckboxes:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

when clicking the '#globalchecker' checkbox, the '.childcheckboxes' don't get checked/un-checked.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code is working fine.Here is fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/aaenbect/

Comment: You should use `change` event instead of `click` event

Comment: Your code is working perfectly for me!!!!!!

Comment: Your code is working , please check just jquery . Please check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('#globalchecker').on('change', function() { //use change

  $('.childcheckboxes:checkbox').prop('checked', $(this).is(":checked")); //use the state of #globalchecker as parameter for checked or not to make it 1 liner

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="globalchecker" type="checkbox" />

<input type="checkbox" class="childcheckboxes" />
<input type="checkbox" class="childcheckboxes" />
<input type="checkbox" class="childcheckboxes" />
<input type="checkbox" class="childcheckboxes" />
```

1. Use change event

Comment: that makes sense since its a checkbox its not being "clicked" but changed it states...let me try.

Comment: what didnt work? can you share all html? do you have multiple `globalchecker` ids?

Comment: nope just one globalchecker id...and when i click it (check it or uncheck it) the childcheckboxes do nothing.

Answer (score 3):

Here is your code this works perfectly.

```js
$('#globalchecker').on('click', function () {
    if($('#globalchecker').is(":checked")){
        $('.childcheckboxes:checkbox').prop('checked',true);
    }
    else{
        $('.childcheckboxes:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="globalchecker" type="checkbox"/>

<input type="checkbox" class="childcheckboxes" />
<input type="checkbox" class="childcheckboxes" />
<input type="checkbox" class="childcheckboxes" />
<input type="checkbox" class="childcheckboxes" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are mostly correct. Here's my version:

```js
var $globalChecker = $('#globalchecker');

var $children = $('.child');

 $globalChecker.on('click', function() {
  if ( $(this).is(":checked") ) {
    $children.prop('checked',true);
  } else {
    $children.prop('checked', false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul class='item-list'>

  <li class='item'>
    <label class='input-w'> <!-- probably put them all in labels like this -->
      <span class='label'>global?</span>
      <input type="checkbox" id="globalchecker" />
    </label>
  </li>
  <li class='item'>
    <input type="checkbox" class='child'/>
  </li>
  <li class='item'>
    <input type="checkbox" class='child'/>
  </li>
  <li class='item'>
    <input type="checkbox" class='child'/>
  </li>
  <li class='item'>
    <input type="checkbox" class='child'/>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JQuery `change` on all checkboxes. Below code checks, if all checkboxes are checked, then even global gets checked. Also, if you click global checkbox then all children checkboxes gets checked too (***works two-way***):

```js
$('#globalchecker').on('change', function() {
  $('.childcheckboxes:checkbox').prop('checked', $(this).is(":checked"));
});

$('.childcheckboxes').on('change', function() {
  if ($('.childcheckboxes').length == $('.childcheckboxes:checked').length) {
    $('#globalchecker').prop('checked', true);
  } else {
    $('#globalchecker').prop('checked', false);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="globalchecker" type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" class="childcheckboxes" />
<input type="checkbox" class="childcheckboxes" />
<input type="checkbox" class="childcheckboxes" />
<input type="checkbox" class="childcheckboxes" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#globalchecker').on('click', function () {
    if($('#globalchecker').is(":checked")){
        $('.childcheckboxes:checkbox').prop('checked',true);
    }
    else{
        $('.childcheckboxes:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="globalchecker" type="checkbox"/> Global Checkbox

<input type="checkbox" class="childcheckboxes" />
<input type="checkbox" class="childcheckboxes" />
<input type="checkbox" class="childcheckboxes" />
<input type="checkbox" class="childcheckboxes" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code working fine for me, here is my solution.
Instead of using `if else` you can you can use the current state of the global checkbox.

```js
$('#globalchecker').on('click', function() {
  var isGlobalChecked = $('#globalchecker').is(":checked");
  $('.childcheckboxes:checkbox').prop("checked", isGlobalChecked);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
global<input id="globalchecker" type="checkbox" />
<br/>
<br/> one
<input type="checkbox" class="childcheckboxes" /> two
<input type="checkbox" class="childcheckboxes" /> three
<input type="checkbox" class="childcheckboxes" /> four
<input type="checkbox" class="childcheckboxes" />
```